# compiler doesn't recognize the dataset (I added using the wizard or the .xsd files)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, namespaces, dataset

I created a DataSet object and DataLayer.cs class in root directory. In the DataLayer class I am using System.Data. But the compiler does not recognize my DataSet. The error asks me if I am missing a directive or an assembly reference. I dont think I am because intellisense does recognize the DataSet keyword, just not the DataSet that I created. The exact code is posted below, obviously you cannot see the DataSet in the Solution Explorer but trust me, it's there. Its exact name is dbCounters.xsd and it has the attached .xss thing. Also, everything is spelled correctly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;

namespace Counters
{
    public class TwCounters
    {
         public void SaveCounters(CountersCache.Type type, DateTime currDateTime, string counter, long value) {

            using (dbCounters.AllCountersDataTable table = new dbCounters.AllCountersDataTable()) {
                table.UpsertAllCounters(System.Convert.ToBoolean(type), currDateTime, counter, value);
            }
            StartCounters();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know is why it doesn't even recognize dbCounters, as far as I can tell it is there, it is spelled right, the Date Layer is referenced, the two files are even in the root directory, I have this same thing working in other projects so whats the problem here?

Comment: is `dbCounters` the full namespace of the data-table in the data layer? Is the data-table type `public` ? what happens if you just make it `AllCountersDataTable` and then (with the caret there) press ctrl+. ?

Comment: Where does `dbCounters` reside, and can we see that code? Is it a namespace, another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSet` isn't a keyword. The compiler doesn't know anything about it specifically.

My *guess* is that your custom `DataSet` is in a different namespace - have a look at the designer-generated code, and add an appropriate `using` directive (or change the namespace to `Counters` to match this code).